# Return array from forEach loop without other functions

Tags: javascript

I have an object which should hold an array of strings and I want to return that array from a .forEach loop.

```
URLs = {
        R: robotIPs.forEach((IP) => {
            console.log(`http://${IP}${config.requestURLs.GETData.GETR}`);
        })
}
```

Now obviously the console.log is working, but how do I make an array and return it as the value to R? RobotIPs is a string array containing the IPs.

Is there any way at all to do this, or do I have to make separate function to handle this?

Comment: replace .forEach with .map :) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want `map`?

```
R: robotIPs.map((IP) => {
  return `http://${IP}${config.requestURLs.GETData.GETR}`
})
```